# The value of TelephonyManager.getPhoneType is related to phone and a fixed constant or related to sim card?

Tags: android, gsm, 3g, telephonymanager, cdma

The value of TelephonyManager.getPhoneType is related to phone and is fixed or related to sim card?  The return value is a fixed constant no matter what the type of sim is ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Th term 'PhoneType' is definitely confusing here - it appears to actually mean the type of device the phone is currently acting as. So the same physical phone could report different values for different subscriptions:

```
TelephonyManager.getPhoneType
```

calls

```
getCurrentPhoneType(getDefaultSubscription())
```

The comments for 'getCurrentPhoneType' indicate that it returns a device type for a particular subscription:

```
/**
 * Returns a constant indicating the device phone type for a subscription.
 *
 * @see #PHONE_TYPE_NONE
 * @see #PHONE_TYPE_GSM
 * @see #PHONE_TYPE_CDMA
 *
 * @param subId for which phone type is returned
 */
```